# SQL QUERY recently hired employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table EMPLOYEES with Name and Starting Date. I have to return the most recently hired five employees. I was able to return only the most recent.

```
SELECT NAME, FAMILY, STARTING_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE STARTING_DATE = (SELECT MAX(STARTING_DATE)FROM EMPLOYEES);
```

I've tried with ROW_NUMBER, but I think in case is not effective.

Comment: What to do in case of ties? E.g. employee five and six with the same starting date: Show 4, 5 or 6 employees then?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT NAME, FAMILY, STARTING_DATE
      FROM EMPLOYEES
      ORDER BY STARTING_DATE DESC
     ) e
WHERE rownum <= 5;
```

Although you can use window functions for this purpose, I don't see any advantage in doing so.

I should note that Oracle 12c offers the simpler, ANSI-standard syntax of:

```
SELECT NAME, FAMILY, STARTING_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY STARTING_DATE DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```